# get data from json file in two methods direct and asynchronously in ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, asynchronous

I have a news application, for performance issue, I used to get json data in two different methods, which are, the first method I got json data direct which contains the data in the first page, meanwhile, I add a code that gets json data which contains the detail of essays and images in asynchronously way to avoid slow loading.
My problem is, when the app is loaded, I click on the essay to get the detail, the detail isn't being loaded yet, the asynchronously method is slow, which let my application has a BUG.
Can you suggest for me an effective way how can I get my json whole data (essays with details) and the application don't load slower.
Please suggest.

Comment: How are you executing async tasks?

Comment: You can priority to the tasks use GCD

Comment: @ŁukaszTomaszewski by using  dispatch_async

Comment: @sairam please can you give me a clear response

Comment: Post your code where are you executing async task.